# How can add to Session without erase previous value in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in `asp.net` want to add value to session without erase previous value,write this code:

```
 Session["behzadList"] = BookIDI.Trim();
```

but that code when run erase previous  value and add it to Session,i want when run that code add new value end of previous value a thing like array in c#,i have to use Session and don't want any other way,thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a `List<string>` in session:

```
List<string> behzadList = Session["behzadList"] as List<string> ?? new List<string>();
behzadList.Add(BookIDI.Trim());
Session["behzadList"] = behzadList;
```

Comment: very good code,thanks that's work,now how can access to Session Array.

Comment: @behzad: it's a list not an array(arrays are fixed-size and lists can add items). I have shown you above how to access the list in the session. You can either loop the list: `foreach(string s in behzadList){...}` or access items at their index: `string first = behzadList[0];`